# Repo removed from software center and can't be installed from (16.04)

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, gdebi

Just in case it's relevant, I'm working with Ubuntu 16.04.

I had a repo (NVIDIA CUDA repo to be specific), from which I installed the `cuda` package.

I removed it from the "Other Software" section in Ubuntu's "Software & Updates" (using the "remove" option).

Now I want to reinstall the package, so I added the same local repo in the same way I originally did:

```
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb
```

And got the output:

```
(Reading database ... 464489 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2 (8.0.61-1) over (8.0.61-1) ...
Setting up cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-8-0-local-ga2 (8.0.61-1) ...
OK
```

Then I update and `sudo apt-get install --reinstall cuda`, but I get:

```
Reinstallation of cuda is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
```

The repo also doesn't appear in my "Other Software" section in Ubuntu's "Software & Updates" (from which it was removed previously).

Does anyone know what might be the cause of it? Thanks ahead

Comment: Updating show no error, but it doesn't 'get' any nvidia/cuda repo.
The synaptic shows the same "software & updates" menu in `settings->repositories` (with no nvidia/cuda repo checked or unchecked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look and started to download the local repo, before I found out that there's also a network repo. Installed it from here, using gdebi https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads

Synaptic shows [image]

and also [image]

and tells me `http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64` has to be set as the correct path for 16.04.

Comment: I tried to purge the cuda-repo-* and cleaning the package manager, but it didn't allow me to reinstall (same error)

Comment: So moving the `.deb` to a different path and renaming it should solve it? Or should I use the "network" repo, so gedbi sees it as a different repo?

Comment: Thank, your solution worked (clean->change repo's path->reinstall repo->reinstall package)